# How to resize an image in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to use some pre-trained computer vision models which require images of a certain dimension. I need to re-size my custom dataset to be a certain dimension. How can I do this with Julia?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia, you can use the `imresize` function as follows:

```
using Images

img_square = imresize(img_source, (224, 224))
```

where `img_source` is the original image which you want to resize and 224x224 is the new image size. You can find out more about the resizing operations in the [Julia Images docs](https://juliaimages.org/latest/examples/spatial_transformation/SpatialTransformations/#Resizing-Operation).

Comment: I don't yhink you need to load the OffsetArrays package..